# How to let neo4j only checks if key duplication and not examine other attributes

Tags: neo4j

For example, suppose a key is set

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Person) ASSERT (n.name) IS NODE KEY
```

Then if you execute the following code

```
MERGE (n1:Person{name:"John",data:13})
MERGE (n2:Person{name:"John",data:13}) // no error
MERGE (n3:Person{name:"John",data:14}) // key duplication error raised
MERGE (n4:Person{name:"Peter",data:15})
CREATE n3->[:pays]->n4 // want this line be executed with n3 being "John" added by the first line
```

a key duplication error will be **raised for the third line**, but **not for the second line**. This means **internally neo4j engine checks if "data" is also duplicated**. However, this might impact performance because my actual "data" attribute is a long text.

**My question is**:

> Can I let neo4j only check key duplication and then give up creation if key exists without examining other attributes?
>
> Also I don't want an error be raised, and need the fifth line be executed where n3 is the existing "John" added by the first line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, I wouldn't worry about the comparison of your data property, especially if this is only comparison on a single node.

You can do an OPTIONAL MATCH instead of a MERGE, but this won't result in a creation attempt if no such node exists:

```
MERGE (n1:Person{name:"John", data:13})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3:Person{name:"John", data:14}) 
MERGE (n4:Person{name:"Peter",data:15})
WITH n4, coalesce(n3, n1) as n3 // if n3 is null will use n1 instead
CREATE (n3)-[:pays]->(n4)
```

Alternately you can use MERGE with an ON CREATE to set the data property in case the MERGE resulted in node creation:

```
MERGE (n1:Person{name:"John", data:13})
MERGE (n3:Person{name:"John"})
ON CREATE SET n3.data = 14
MERGE (n4:Person{name:"Peter",data:15})
CREATE (n3)-[:pays]->(n4)
```

In the above, because you merged n3 by the name property, it will match on the same node as n1, and will not set the data property to 14 because the MERGE didn't result in node creation.

Just to note, you'll get similar behavior if you just have a unique constraint on :Person(name). The major difference between unique constraints and node keys is that node keys also include an inherent existence constraint on the property (the property must exist on all nodes of that label), and that multiple properties on the node can comprise a node key. Also, node key constraints (like existence constraints) are for enterprise edition only. For community edition, use unique constraints instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try and see if there is performance difference. We have 80 million nodes to add, so that is significant. We estimates neo4j spends 70% of the time to check non-key attributes, and that is not a tolerable waste for us.

Comment: For significant numbers of nodes to add, please ensure you're using LOAD CSV (USING PERIODIC COMMIT) or otherwise batching your loads so you don't blow out your heap.